# Can not install TypeScript 0.9.1.1 explicitly for VS2013, it installs version 1.0.3.0

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I want to install TypeScript 0.9.1.1 only and no other version for MS Visual Studio 2013. 
I have tried the exe file available here [Download Link for Typescript 0.9.1.1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/F/2FFA1FBA-97CA-4FFB-8ED7-A4AE06398948/TypeScriptSetup.0.9.1.1.exe)

It installs Version 1.0.3.0 (checked from CMD using command "**tsc -- version**")

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your PATH environment variable is wrong, you can check that by executing `echo %PATH%` and you will probably see something like`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;` and maybe some extra ones which are before the 0.9 one.

You can also try executing `where tsc` and maybe you find the path there to the 0.9.1.1 version.

If you find that path you can add it to the environment. You can change that by going to the Control Panel -> System & Security -> and on the left there is "Advanced System settings", click on It and a popup will open. Chose the tab "advanced" there and click the button "Environment variables", there you can change your path. Make sure to add the 0.9.1.1 version before the 1.0 version.

You need to restart cmd after changing this.